# XML not working witg GPS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, gps

```
var geo:Geolocation; 

if (Geolocation.isSupported) 
{ 
    geo = new Geolocation(); 
    geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, updateHandler); 
    geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(10000);
} 
else 
{ 
    geoTextField.text = "Geolocation feature not supported"; 
} 

function updateHandler(event:GeolocationEvent):void 
{ 
    lat = event.latitude.toString();
    lon = event.longitude.toString();
    var lat:String;
    var lon:String;
    trace(lat);
    trace(lon);
    var weather_xml_url:String = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?  lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&units=metric&lang=lv&mode=xml";
    trace(weather_xml_url);
    var weather:XML = new XML();
    var weather_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(weather_xml_url);
    var weatherLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(weather_url);
    trace(weather);
    weatherLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, weatherLoaded);

    function weatherLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        weather = XML(weatherLoader.data);
        temp_txt.text = weather.list.item.temperature.@value;
        wind_txt.text = weather.list.item.wind.speed.@value+ "m/s";

        var weather_icon:String = weather.list.item.weather.@icon;
        icons_mc.gotoAndStop(weather_icon);
    }
}
```

When i trace trace(lat); trace(lon); it works perfect
When i trace trace(weather_xml_url); it works perfect
When i trace trace(weather); it send me a null

Why it not reading xml i tried to the web the xml address is correct, but it not loading weatherLoader function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you place `trace(weather);` in incorrect place. It may be available only after load complete, not before.

Second, try to write `weather = new XML(weatherLoader.data);` instead of `weather = XML(weatherLoader.data);`

`XML()` is just casting Object to XML class, but `new XML()` will create new XML instance.

And main problem: you forgot to start load XML. Now you have next code:

```
var weather_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var weatherLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(weather_url);
weatherLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, weatherLoaded);
```

It creates `URLRequest`, then creates `URLLoader` based on `URLRequest` and adds listener on load complete. **But, it doesn't start loading**. So, to fix it you need to add next line:

```
weatherLoader.load(weather_url);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see main problem: you doesn't call load() method. I updated answer, try it.

Comment: but i get back Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

Comment: Add argument "weather_url" in load() method. And move "trace(weather);" to line "weather = new XML(weatherLoader.data);" - does it show something?

Comment: I add  trace(weather); after weather = XML(weatherLoader.data); and it loads xml data but anyway it cant get right...

Comment: Ok. Then maybe problem in your parse code? You didn't show XML example, but I tried api from your code. Try to remove '.list.item' part from your parse code. Example: 'weather.temperature.@value' instead of 'weather.list.item.temperature.@value'.

Comment: sorry the code was right my mistake that i didn't check the xml after the i changed to geo coordinates...